# In Erlang, what are the benefits of using ets instead of process dictionary within a process?

Tags: erlang

I think using ets will still introduce similar side effects.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ETS is not garbage collected since it is stored in a heap outside of erlang processes. This means that when you put something into ets it is copied into it, and when you take it out, you get a copy in your process. Making lots of ets lookups can then lead to excess consing in your process (but this is only relevant for very high througputs).

The process dictionary is garbage collected. It is stored in the process's own heap. So when you look things up in it you get a reference to the exact same value you put in it. The values stored in the process dictionary are not compacted.

Both approaches are non-pure, i.e. they have side-effects. Yes it is bad, and yes it is not why we have both alternatives.

Comment: Almost all Erlang books say we should stay away from process library but I think using ets is not much different.

Comment: "Almost all Erlang books"... does that mean two out of three? =)

Comment: What do you mean by "compacted" regarding the values stored in the process dictionary? What does "compacted" mean here?

Comment: ETS is like an Erlang process implemented in C. You can send it table rows and fetch table rows. It will store them in a native way implemented in C, in non garbage collected heap space. That is how I meant compacted. 

The process dictionary is just normal erlang terms. But the difference in compactness shouldnt be that big, only that it is in GC:ed heap and you will have problems after a few thousand rows.

Honestly though, I wrote this 2009 and I dont really remember what I meant.

Comment: « So when you look things up in it you get a reference to the exact same value you put in it. The values stored in the process dictionary are not compacted. »
So you mean a pointer right? If I have a huge value that I need to fetch 3 times (from another process/DB) I can cache it there and the memory footprint will be lower as the same pointer will be used for my 3 instances of that data. Is that right?

Answer (score 13):

ETS more or less behaves as if the table was in a separate process and requests are messages sent to that process. While it is not implemented with processes that the properties of ETS are modeled like that. It is in fact possible to implement ETS with processes.

This means that the side effect properties are consistent with the rest of Erlang.

The process dictionary is like nothing else in Erlang and adding it was a big mistake. There is no reason to use the process dictionary instead of one of the process local dictionaries like dict or gb_trees.

Comment: I guess a difference between ETS and the "process-based ETS" would be that the former can be accessed truly concurrently when using fine locks, while the latter will always enforce synchronization (a.k.a. serialization).

Comment: Not really from one process as accessing ETS is synchronous so the "calling" process has to wait till it gets a "reply" from ETS. The difference is that the process dictionary will always be one within the context of that process while ETS will be a synchronized access to shared data.

Comment: I see rvirding has commented, and he is one of the gurus of Erlang, but on this point I humbly differ.  

I do see a need for (and have used) process dictionary for housekeeping functions within a process. 

Sometimes we need to store state within a process for a function that is not part of the processes main function, for example a logger may maintain state, and putting logger state into main application logic is bad.

Comment: Why was adding the process dictionary a mistake? I only think of being so because it opens the door for side-effects. It seems a nice means for the functions called by a process to access process-local data, instead of adding an argument to all functions in which to pass the calling process specific data. Also, it seems according to another post on this page that it is much faster than ETS (in fact it seems a kind of ETS). Please, clarify me why was a mistake. Thanks

Comment: The example usage I gave in the previous comment is one of the possible uses of the process dictionary listed in [How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love Erlang's Process Dictionary](https://prog21.dadgum.com/53.html) under the name "Handling tricky data flow in high-level code".

Comment: A similar entry on the uses of the process dictionary is [On the Use of the Process Dictionary in Erlang](https://ferd.ca/on-the-use-of-the-process-dictionary-in-erlang.html).

Comment: The Erlang's team opinion is to "use with care" and "do not over use - try the clean version first" see [Erlang Advanced Topics](https://www.erlang.org/course/advanced#dict).

Answer (score 11):

Benefits of ETS over process dictionary are:

- Other processes can access the ETS table directly
- ETS gives you searching / matching / iteration facilities, while the process dictionary is only a key-value store.
- You can save/load tables to files in one step
- If your owner process dies the table can be inherited by someone else, so the data is not lost.

Answer (score 6):

No doubt that ETS has much more functionality and is more sophisticated. But...

- As the process dictionary update/lookup operations move only the references, not the whole data (see the accurate answer by Christian), it can be much faster, especially for big data structures. Once I refactored a part of code to keep the big and frequently accessed data structures in proc. dict instead of ETS and we had a 30% speedup in that part of the code.
- In many cases the data is accessed only by a single process. In that case I don't see a  big theoretical difference between the proc.dict and ETS. Both serve for keeping side effects in memory.
  Besides, you can access the proc.dict of another process like

  > process_info(whereis(net_kernel),dictionary).